# How to run nhttp.exe with password?

Tags: xpages, lotus-domino

I want to create .bat file, what must call nhttp.exe and put in this .exe file my password.But noone commands don`t works for me.

```
nhttp.exe 'my-pass'
nhttp.exe|'my-pass'
'my-pass'|nhttp.exe
nhttp.exe<fileWithpass.txt

[2388:0002-4180] The ID file being used is: C:\Program Files 
(x86)\IBM\Notes\myFileId.id 
[2388:0002-4180] Enter password (press the Esc key to abort):
```

Comment: nttp.exe is a process controlled by the Domino server and can not (to my knowledge) be run like this. What are you really trying to achieve?

Comment: Hi, i have application Xpage on local host and i dont want to open Domino Designer for up http server. I want write .bat file directly for up http server from desktop.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Domino Designer's local nhttp is not the same as the server's nhttp with regard to XPages. If you're doing development, install a Domino server locally. That is best practice and why I worked with IBM for over a year to get a non-production license for Domino, which is what's now available with the Community Server license. Links for the Community Server (a separate package but same code-set as the full server) can be found at the bottom of Thomas Hampel's blog post https://blog.thomashampel.com/blog/tomcat2000.nsf/dx/v10.0.1-has-arrived.htm. There is also the IBM Docker image which can be used to run a Domino server in Docker for Windows https://github.com/IBM/domino-docker.

Answer (score 3):

Just to give you a solution (while it is a better idea to install a local dev server, as Paul suggested):

You can start nhttp.exe with a different notes.ini and use a password-less ID file

```
nhttp.exe =/path/to/notes-nhttp.ini
```

*(The slashes depend on your OS)*

In the INI file, you can set a different Notes ID by changing the following parameter:

```
KeyFileName=/path/to/notes-nhttp.id
```